# MetroSE: A Windows 8 Stack Exchange App

Tags: app

Experience Stack Exchange like never before. With MetroSE, you have over 180 Stack Exchange sites at your fingertips. Browse interesting questions on your favorite sites. Search questions from anywhere at any time. View your user profile and your top questions/answers for each registered site. All of this from the comfort of you tablet, desktop, or laptop.

#### Main Page:

[image]

#### Snapped View:

[image]

#### Searching:

[image]

[image]

### Bug Reporting/Feedback

You can either send an email to `cases[at]kronoskoders[dot]fogbugz[dot]com` or you can add cases manually [using the online gui.](https://kronoskoders.fogbugz.com/default.asp?pg=pgPublicEdit)

Answer (score 1):

This is neat!

Here are some questions / suggestions / feedback:

1. Logging in with a custom OpenID is a little difficult:

   [image]

   As you can see, it is hard to type into the box. Perhaps some padding can be added to the page.
2. The question titles are being truncated after 3 or 4 words:

   [image]

   Is there any way more of the title could be shown?
3. If I visit my profile page, change the site, click a question, and then go back - the site reverts to Stack Overflow. It would be nice if the page remembered what site I had selected.

Comment: Thanks!  I'll start working on these right away.  If you come across any other issues or feature requests feel free to [report them here](https://kronoskoders.fogbugz.com/default.asp?pg=pgPublicEdit).

Comment: Ah, okay. I will do that.